# Value inside object won't change after passing by reference

Tags: c++, object, reference

Why does the value inside the object not change although I passed by reference.

```
class ref_test {
public:
    explicit ref_test(const int& a) : a(a) {};

    const int& get_a() noexcept { return a;}
private:
    const int a;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int b = 10;
    ref_test r(b);

    b = 15;
    std::cout << r.get_a() << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
10
15

As far as I understand, I pass the memory location to the object which is not allowed to change it (since it is marked as const). If I then change the value after passing, the value inside the memory location should change and so should change the value inside the object too.
If that was true, passing by reference should not be safe to pass to an object since the value might be changed afterwards. Therefore, is it better to pass by value to an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The private int inside the class is not a reference. So the construction in the member initializer is *copying* the argument.

If you change the member variable to

```
int const &a;
```

then the program will print `15 15`

If this is not the behaviour you want, then simply take the constructor argument by value.

Comment: I changed the private member variable to `const int& a` but this does not change the output of the posted program.

Comment: Ok, seems to be a problem within my IDE, strange.

Answer (score 0):

Within the class `ref_test` the private data member `a` has no referenced type

```
const int a;
```

If you want that this data member had a referenced type you have to write

```
const int &a;
```

In this case the data member `a` will refer to the object passed to the constructor of the class.

To see the changes insert one more output statement before the reassignment of the variable b.

```
std::cout << r.get_a() << std::endl;
b = 15;
std::cout << r.get_a() << std::endl;
```

Another approach is to use the standard class `std::reference_wrapper`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class ref_test 
{
public:
    explicit ref_test(const int& a) : a(a) {};

    const int & get_a() noexcept { return a;}

private:
    const int &a;
};

class ref_test2 
{
public:
    explicit ref_test2( const int& a ) : a(a) {};

    const int & get_a() noexcept { return ( a.get() );}

private:
    std::reference_wrapper<const int> a;
};

int main() 
{
    int b = 10;
    ref_test r(b);

    std::cout << r.get_a() << '\n';
    std::cout << b << '\n';

    b = 15;

    std::cout << r.get_a() << '\n';
    std::cout << b << '\n';

    std::cout << '\n';

    ref_test2 r2( b );

    std::cout << r2.get_a() << '\n';
    std::cout << b << '\n';

    b = 20;

    std::cout << r2.get_a() << '\n';
    std::cout << b << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
10
10
15
15

15
15
20
20
```

Comment: What is the advantage of the wrapper?

Comment: @SimonPio. It will bot allow to bind a temporary object.